# Group hourly tagged data bonded by start & end data to proportional daily data using Pandas DF

Tags: pandas

I'm using unavailability data per product that have hourly start & end  per each period that the product was unavailable, following is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
unavability = pd.DataFrame([[dt.datetime(2017, 10, 19,11), dt.datetime(2017, 10, 19,12),'broom'],
                       [dt.datetime(2017, 10, 19,9),dt.datetime(2017, 10, 19,10),'broom'], 
                       [dt.datetime(2017, 10, 19,1), dt.datetime(2017, 10, 19,2),'bike'],
                       [dt.datetime(2017, 10, 19,22),dt.datetime(2017, 10, 20,3),'bike']],
                      columns=['start_date', 'end_date','product'])
print unavability
      start_date            end_date product
0 2017-10-19 11:00:00 2017-10-19 12:00:00   broom
1 2017-10-19 09:00:00 2017-10-19 10:00:00   broom
2 2017-10-19 01:00:00 2017-10-19 02:00:00    bike
3 2017-10-19 22:00:00 2017-10-20 03:00:00    bike
```

I'm looking to group the data into unavailability proportion per each date & product, so i would like to convert the `Data Frame` above into the following, keep in mind that i want it to work even if the unavailability period lasts for more than 49 hours (overlaps 3 days

```
desired=pd.DataFrame([[dt.datetime(2017, 10, 19),'broom',22/24.0],#2 houres of unavalability
              [dt.datetime(2017, 10, 20),'broom',24/24.0], #Product fully available at that day
              [dt.datetime(2017, 10, 19),'bike',22/24.0], # 2 hour of unavalability - from 22 to 24
              [dt.datetime(2017, 10, 20),'bike',21/24.0]], # 3 hour of unavalability - from 00 to 3
              columns=['date', 'product','avalability_proportion'])
print desired
        date product  avalability_proportion
0 2017-10-19   broom                0.916667
1 2017-10-20   broom                1.000000
2 2017-10-19    bike                0.916667
3 2017-10-20    bike                0.875000
```

Some toughs:
I thought of creating for a start a transformation that would create for all available products the theoretical hours as suggested here: [Fill missing timeseries data using pandas or numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241692/fill-missing-timeseries-data-using-pandas-or-numpy) , then create a join to the original data, and some how fill it, not sure if its a smart one.

Any help on this would be awesome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My silly solution and hope this will help:

```
df = unavability
# if date is changed, remember changed rows
df['is_date_changed'] = df.start_date.dt.date != df.end_date.dt.date
df.loc[df.is_date_changed,'intermediate_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.end_date.dt.date)
df_date_is_changed = df.loc[df.is_date_changed]
df_date_not_changed = df.loc[~df.is_date_changed]

# expand every changed row to two, 
# and append those rows to the date_not_changed dataframe.
# for example,
# 2017-10-19 22:00:00   2017-10-20 03:00:00
# will be expand into two rows:
# 2017-10-19 22:00:00   2017-10-20 00:00:00
# 2017-10-20 00:00:00   2017-10-20 03:00:00
for idx,row in df_date_is_changed.iterrows():
    row1 = [row['start_date'],row['intermediate_date'],row['product'],None,None]
    df_date_not_changed.loc[-1] = row1
    df_date_not_changed.index = df_date_not_changed.index + 1
    row2 = [row['intermediate_date'],row['end_date'],row['product'],None,None]
    df_date_not_changed.loc[-1] = row2
    df_date_not_changed.index = df_date_not_changed.index + 1

df = df_date_not_changed
df['date'] = df.apply(
    lambda x:min(x['start_date'],x['end_date']),
axis=1)
df.date = df.date.dt.date
df['time_delta'] = df.end_date - df.start_date

df.groupby(['product','date']).agg({'time_delta':'sum'})
```

Comment: thanks for the nice answer, though keep in mind that your splitting the data into two frames  for two following dates, what will happen if i have unavailability that lasts for 3 days?

Comment: You can append more rows, each row representing a day. But maybe it looks very stupid. And you have to conside time window overlaps.

Comment: Also notice that i want a column of proportion, and not time delta, i want it as proportion of 24 hours not the time diff :)

Comment: The proportion could be calced based on the time delta, so I just ignore that.