# Convert range of two date time's into a list of dates and count of seconds per that date python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm interested in creating a function that gets two following `datetime` objects (start date and end date) as input and returns a list of tuples. I would like a tuple for each date between start and end date, and the number of seconds in this date. For example:

```
import datetime
#there are total 86400 seconds within a date
start_date=datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 17,22,30,0) # this has 60*60+60*30= 5400 within that date
end_date=datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 19,10,30,11) # this date has  10*60*60+60*30+11=37811 seconds

desired_list_of_tupple=[(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 17),5400),(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 18),86400),(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 19),37811)]
```

For 2017-10-17 number of seconds is 5400 (number of seconds between 22:30 and midnight.

For 2017-10-18 number of seconds is 86400 (whole day is in range).

For 2017-10-19 number of seconds is 37811 (number of seconds from midnight  up until 10:30:11 ).

Any help on that would be great!

Comment: `# this has 60*60+60*30= 5400 within that date` What does that mean? Why would a date have *x* amount of seconds "in" it?

Comment: Ill edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def date_range(start, end):                               
    current = start
    while True:
        next_stop = (current + timedelta(days=1)).replace(
            hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
        if next_stop > end:
            next_stop = end
        yield current.date(), (next_stop - current).total_seconds()
        if next_stop == end:
            break
        current = next_stop
```

This is a generator function, so you'll need to do `list(date_range(start_date, end_date))` to get a list.

I have not properly tested edge cases (like end_date being the same day or earlier than start date etc.), I'm not sure what you want for that, but the output for your specified data is correct. Depending on your use case, watch out for gotchas around summer daylight savings time zones - you'll need 'timezone aware' datetime objects for that.

Comment: thanks, thats perfect!  this is for answering that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052626/group-hourly-tagged-data-bonded-by-start-end-data-to-proportional-daily-data-u , you are more that welcome to answer is, i'm not very happy with the current answer